# How to Sum two or more JSON object into One

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

hi i have following JSON objects;

```
var obj1 = {"a":1,"b":1,"c":1};
var obj2 = {"a":2,"b":2,"c":2};
var obj3 = {"a":3,"b":3,"c":3};
```

i want to sum,or subtract above 3 json Objects
i want final result as

```
  {"a":6,"b":6,"c":6}
```

i know it is very simple by using different types of loop. but i want to know whether is there any function exists in javascript to merge multiple JSON objects and add or subtract each properties(without loop).

is there possible like `reduce` function in array:
like below:

```
var squares = arr.concat(arr2).reduce((t,n)=>t+n);
```

Thanks

Comment: `,'c'=1}` is invalid syntax...

Comment: invalid syntax!

Comment: this is just example of json object having key value pair

Answer (score 6):

There's no such built-in function that can accomplish something like that automatically, but it's trivial to write your own code that does what you want:

```js
var obj1 = {"a":1,"b":1,'c':1};
var obj2 = {"a":2,"b":2,'c':2};
var obj3 = {"a":3,"b":3,'c':3};
const combined = [obj1, obj2, obj3].reduce((a, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
  });
  return a;
});
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop over one of your `object` properties  and construct the result:

```
let res = {};
for (p in obj1) {
  res[p] = obj1[p] + (obj2[p] || 0) + (obj3[p] || 0);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj1 = {"a":1,"b":1,"c":1};
var obj2 = {"a":2,"b":2,"c":2};
var obj3 = {"a":3,"b":3,"c":3};

let res = {};

for (p in obj1) {
  res[p] = obj1[p] + (obj2[p] || 0) + (obj3[p] || 0);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: what if i have objects are dynamic ? i mean there may e three or more objects dynamically

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani What do you mean by dynamic? You can't just guess the names in your code, you will need to store them in an `array` if there are many and *dynamic* objects.

Comment: there is a checklistdropdown and each option in dropdown have one JSON object. so selected option's object get sum of substract

Comment: Please update your question, with all the relevant code.